# PLEASE ANSWER Sterling vs Combustion Engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, automotive-engineering, engines, fuel-economy

This may be difficult to answer but, theoretically, if you had a car with a sterling engine that produces say approximately 300 horsepower how much of any specific heat source would need to be used if the car had a mass of 1.5 tonnes in order for the car to travel 100 km. Furthermore, what would a combustion engine that produces the same power in a car that has the same body and mass use in terms of fuel compared to the sterling engine?

What are the requirements for a sterling engine to perform at the same level as a combustion engine in an automobile?

Comment: Have you researched Stirling engines? If not you should.

Comment: @SolarMike I have researched them but I was wondering if anyone on here had any additional knowledge that could either save time or simplify the information I have found on google scholar to information that was relevant to my question regarding the mathematical differences between a sterling engine and an internal combustion engine that produces the same number of horsepower regarding fuel/energy consumption.

Comment: Given your question here, this looks like homework : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/27002/10902

Comment: See https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/stirling-engine.html

Comment: Also search on here : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/5709/10902

Comment: @SolarMike It's a pity that "real-world-physics" link omits the one basic fact that makes Stirling engines work at all - i.e. the fact that the two pistons are linked *and move 90 degrees out of phase with each other.* Without that fact, the subject can look like magic.